# Attribute Error in python. Object has no attribute

Tags: python, oop

This code is part of a bigger program that uses the google Sheets API to get data from a cloud database (not really relevant, but a bit of context never hurt!)

I have this black of code in one python file named 'oop.py'

```
class SetupClassroom:
    def __init__(self, arraynumber='undefined', tkroot='undefined'):
        self.arraynumber = arraynumber
        self.tkroot = tkroot

    def setarraynumber(self, number):
        from GUI_Stage_3 import showclassroom
        self.arraynumber = number
        print ('set array number:', number)

        showclassroom()

    def settkroot(self, tkrootinput):
        self.tkroot = tkrootinput
```

self.tkroot has been assigned by another part of the code. This bit works, as I have already tested that it is being assigned, however, when I call 'self.tkroot' in another another file like this

```
def showclassroom():
    from oop import SetupClassroom
    username = current_user.username
    classnumber = getnumberofuserclassrooms(username)
    if SetupClassroom.arraynumber > classnumber:
        errorwindow('you are not enrolled in that many classrooms!')
    else:

        classtoget = SetupClassroom.arraynumber
        print('classtoget:', classtoget)
        root = SetupClassroom.tkroot
        name_label = Label(root, text=classtoget)

        getclassroom(username, classtoget)
SetupClassroom = SetupClassroom
```

I get this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/jonathansalmon/PycharmProjects/Coursework_GUI/GUI_Stage2_better.py", line 176, in <lambda>
    l0 = ttk.Button(teacher_root, text=button0text, command=lambda: (SetupClassroom.setarraynumber(SetupClassroom, number=button0text), SetupClassroom.settkroot(SetupClassroom, 'teacher_root')))
  File "/Users/jonathansalmon/PycharmProjects/Coursework_GUI/oop.py", line 99, in setarraynumber
    showclassroom()
  File "/Users/jonathansalmon/PycharmProjects/Coursework_GUI/GUI_Stage_3.py", line 29, in showclassroom
    root = SetupClassroom.tkroot
AttributeError: type object 'SetupClassroom' has no attribute 'tkroot'
```

I tried setting it up in the python console and it worked, so I have no idea what the problem is.
If anyone could help, it would be very much appreciated
Thanks!
John

Comment: You need to make an instance of the class. I'm wondering why `SetupClassroom.arraynumber` didn't raise an error first.

Comment: ah, sorry, If understand what you mean, I did accidentally leave that out of the main question, I am adding that now (SetupClassroom = SetupClassroom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an instance of class, it will create the attribute in `__init__`, `self.tkroot` is the attribute of instance not class:

```
setupClassroom = SetupClassroom()
print(setupClassroom.tkroot)
```

Hope that will help you.